# Regex to extract the content(multiple lines) in between certain tags

Tags: python, regex

I've got this regex to extract a single line between two tags.

> Example- Tag: Hello world

Regex I've used is

```
\Tag:+(.*)\n\
```

> Extracted Info = Hello World

However I can't seem to find a regex to extract multiple lines until the next tag is found.

> Example- Tag: This is a test string to show the content that has to be extracted.This is a test string to show the content that has to be extracted.This is a test string to show the content that.
>
> Tag: ABCDEF

Regex I've tried using is

```
'\Tag:+(.*)Tag:\
```

> Desired Extracted Info = This is a test string to show the content that has to be extracted.This is a test string to show the content that has to be extracted.This is a test string to show the content that.

Comment: Your examples are not consistent

Comment: You could try with: [__`Tag:\s*(.*)\s*Tag`__](https://regex101.com/r/qZ5hWB/1) using the appropriate flags.

Comment: What if I have a variable that contains many tags? How would I include that in the regex?